# How to export decision trees from GradientTreeBoost in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, random-forest, machine-learning

I'm running the Google Earth Engine examples for [`ee.Classifier.smileGradientTreeBoost`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-classifier-smilegradienttreeboost) and [`ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-classifier-smilerandomforest), which are basically the same but with different training methods.

I was wondering how can I get the decision trees generated by the classifier training, so I can export and reuse them with [`ee.Classifier.decisionTreeEnsemble`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-classifier-decisiontreeensemble)

All of the examples that I found were using `smileRandomForest`, which export the trees as a list with the `explain()` method. But `smileGradientTreeBoost` doesn't.

Is it possible to access decision trees of a `smileGradientTreeBoost`? What I am trying to achieve is to save the trained model for later use, avoiding the need to retrain it each time.

I'm really new to machine learning.

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently save GTB trees.